# Python Debugger converts backspace to `^H`

Tags: python, pdb

I'm working in a Linux server environment and use the [Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) frequently. I haven't had this issue before on a previous server I was using, but I noticed after I switched that pressing Backspace outputs `^H` when I'm in the interactive shell. It works fine in the terminal though.

Does anyone know what the issue might be? Thanks.

**Edit**

None of the navigation keys seem to work either.

Comment: Probably wrong terminal settings, but you reveal nothing about how you are set up. Is this a bare Linux console or an `xterm`? What does `stty` and `echo "$TERM"` print at the shell prompt? How exactly are you running Python?

Comment: I actually found a solution. My terminal and Python weren't the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. The problem wasn't my Python or anything, but an external library called ["Weights & Biases"](https://www.wandb.com/)  that I'm using. It turns out that W&B doesn't support `readline`, and simply running things like `pip install readline` or `pip install gnureadline` didn't help.

I had to use the [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) tool to wrap my program.

Now if I run `rlwrap python blahblah.py --argument1 ...` everything works.